# FFmpeg UDP timeout, retrying with TCP callback

Tags: ios, tcp, ffmpeg, udp, rtsp

I'm reading some `RTSP` stream in an iOS app using `FFmpeg`. If the firewall or other services stops the network from receiving via `UDP`, `FFmpeg` nicely falls back to reading via `TCP`. My question is: How can I be notified that the fallback to `TCP` happened? I need to know whether the app is reading the stream via `UDP` or `TCP` and still let `FFmpeg` do its nice fallback.
Is there a callback for this? Is there a way to get the protocol that is using?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: After the connection is made one can read the lower transport protocol from the `AVFormatContext`'s private data (`priv_data`). Bellow is how I'm doing it:

```
-(BOOL)lowerTransportProtocolIsUDP
{
    RTSPState* rtsp_state = (RTSPState*) _avFmtCtx->priv_data;

    enum RTSPLowerTransport lowerTransportProtocol = rtsp_state->lower_transport;

    NSLog(@"lowerTransportProtocol = %d", lowerTransportProtocol);

    if (lowerTransportProtocol == RTSP_LOWER_TRANSPORT_UDP) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Where `_avFmtCtx` is a `AVFormatContext` instance.